"wrapping" subroutines in Fortran
I am new to Fortran and am curious about how to correctly 'wrap' subroutines.
E.g. suppose I have a main program that calls some subroutine outer, that checks a flag and then calls some other subroutine, inner_1 or inner_2, depending on the value of flag. It passes arguments along to the inner subroutines.
Naively, I can just create a subroutine outer than checks the flag and calls the inner subroutines. But this requires declaring all variables passed to outer just to pass them along to the inner subroutines. For many arguments, this seems cumbersome.
Is this the standard way to accomplish this, or is there some better way that I don't know about?
I wrote a working example:
program main

    use m_mod,  only : outer

    implicit none

    real    :: a = 1.0
    integer :: b = 1
    integer :: flag

    flag = 1
    call outer(a,b,flag)

    flag = 2
    call outer(a,b,flag)

end program main

module m_mod

    implicit none

    private
    public  :: outer

    contains

    subroutine outer(a,b,flag)

        real, intent(in)    :: a
        integer, intent(in) :: b
        integer, intent(in) :: flag

        if (flag == 1) then
            call inner_1(a,b)
        else
            call inner_2(a,b)
        end if

    end subroutine outer

    subroutine inner_1(a,b)

        real, intent(in)    :: a
        integer, intent(in) :: b

        write(*,*) "inner_1-a", a
        write(*,*) "inner_1-b", b

    end subroutine inner_1

    subroutine inner_2(a,b)

        real, intent(in)    :: a
        integer, intent(in) :: b

        write(*,*) "inner_2-a", a
        write(*,*) "inner_2-b", b

    end subroutine inner_2

end module m_mod 

which outputs
 inner_1-a   1.00000000    
 inner_1-b           1
 inner_2-a   1.00000000    
 inner_2-b           1

as expected. I just want to know if there is a better way to do this!

Welcome, use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions and follow the instructions displayed in tue short description of the tags you add. Your signature is displayed under your question or answer automatically and hence should not be wrotten in tue wuestion body.

There are many "complicated" ways which may be "better" in some subjective way, but you should ask yourself: is the method I've chosen a clear expression of the logic I wish to implement? It seems hard to argue that it isn't.

@francescalus thanks for the input. It definitely “worked” so I was happy, but I wanted to know if there was a standard, better way. Your answer tells me there isn’t, so I'm happy. If it’s worth it to you, type that as answer and I’ll accept it.

If you want to keep the inner routines independent (i.e. they can be called from other routines than the wrapping one) there's no obvious other solution. Otherwise you may transform them into contained routines, without having to repeat the argument list:
module m_mod

    implicit none

    private
    public  :: outer

    contains

    subroutine outer(a,b,flag)

        real, intent(in)    :: a
        integer, intent(in) :: b
        integer, intent(in) :: flag

        if (flag == 1) then
            call inner_1()
        else
            call inner_2()
        end if
    
    CONTAINS
        ! a, b, (and flag), are available to the contained routines
        ! thanks to host association

        subroutine inner_1()

            write(*,*) "inner_1-a", a
            write(*,*) "inner_1-b", b

        end subroutine inner_1

        subroutine inner_2()

            write(*,*) "inner_2-a", a
            write(*,*) "inner_2-b", b

        end subroutine inner_2

    end subroutine outer

end module m_mod 


I want them to be private, and the wrapping routine is the only one that talks to them, so this is perfect.
